# Getting Server response (400): Invalid classifier "Framework :: Django :: 1.10" from Pypi

Tags: python, django, pypi

I´m packaging a Django app, I ran:

```
$ python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

After that I ran:

```
$ python setup.py register -r pypitest
```

I get the following error:

```
...
writing manifest file 'acp_calendar.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running check
Registering acp-calendar to https://testpypi.python.org/pypi
Server response (400): Invalid classifier "Framework :: Django :: 1.10"
```

This are my classifiers on my setup.py

```
classifiers=[
    'Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable',
    'Framework :: Django',
    'Framework :: Django :: 1.10',
    'Framework :: Django :: 1.9',
    'Framework :: Django :: 1.8',
    'Intended Audience :: Developers',
    'License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License',
    'Natural Language :: English',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
    'Intended Audience :: Developers',
],
```

Answer (score 3):

## This has been recently resolved! You may now use the classifier on `testpypi`!

I'm keeping the old answer below for historical reasons:

---

I recently encoutered this myself, and the reason for this is because that `classifier` is **NOT** available on `testpypi`.

Take a look at:

- The classifiers on [`testpypi`](https://testpypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=list_classifiers)

**Versus**

- The classifiers on [`pypi`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=list_classifiers)

A quick search will show that `pypi` does indeed have `Framework :: Django :: 1.10` where as `testpypi` does not!

It also appears to have been [recently reported as a problem.](https://github.com/pypa/pypi-legacy/issues/550)

Comment: So ? What to do ? Stop using Classifier or there is some hack to make around ?

Comment: Considering that it's missing from just the `test` site @iMitwe you will be able to use it on a live production package on `pypi`

Comment: @luis-berrocal this has been fixed and you may use this solution now.

Comment: @iMitwe this has been fixed recently, you can use the classifier now.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error

```
HTTPError: 400 Bad Request from test.pypi.org/legacy Invalid value for classifiers. 
Error: Classifier 'Framework :: Django :: 3.1.7' is not a valid classifier
```

I fixed it by changing 3.1.7 to 3.1 according to https://test.pypi.org/pypi?%3Aaction=list_classifiers